# Scrapy - Missing data after request form

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using this website to get latitude and longitude of different cities: https://www.latlong.net/.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
import json

with open('C:/Users/coppe/tutorial/cities.json') as json_file:  
    cities = json.load(json_file)

class communes_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "geo"
    start_urls = ['https://www.latlong.net/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for city in cities:
            yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formid='place', formdata={'place': city['city']}, callback=self.get_geo)

    def get_geo(self, response):
        yield {'coord': response.css('input::text').get()}
```

The code run totally fine but the output I get is not correct. The default output value is (0,0) and should be something like (50.643909, 5.571560) after the form. However the crawler still gathers (0,0) as an answer. I guess the issue comes from the website but I cannot identify it.

JSON sample:

```
[{"city": "Anvers, BE"},
{"city": "Gand, BE"},
{"city": "Charleroi, BE"},
{"city": "Li\u00e8ge, BE"},
{"city": "Ville de Bruxelles, BE"},
{"city": "Schaerbeek, BE"},
{"city": "Anderlecht, BE"},
{"city": "Bruges, BE"},
{"city": "Namur, BE"},
{"city": "Louvain, BE"},
{"city": "Molenbeek-Saint-Jean, BE"}]
```

Comment: The fromid is wrong, the value is `frmPlace`. But this is not the reason why this is not working, the reason is, the website is displaying the result trough javascript. Search `sm(` in the DOM you will see the JS script which display the result. I suggest you to use scrapy Splash or Selenium if you want to easily scrape what you want.

Comment: You can also find a way to parse the value inside the JS script (using Regex: `sm\((?P<lat>\d+\.?\d+),(?P<long>\d+\.?\d+)`). The JS script will only work if you set your cookies correctly (I can manage to get the lat/long trough Postman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code, this is working in my side:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import json

import scrapy

class communes_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "geo"
    allowed_domains = ["www.latlong.net"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.latlong.net/']

    custom_settings = {
        'COOKIES_ENABLED': True,
    }

    # This regex is not perfect and can be improved
    LAT_LONG_REGEX = 'sm\((?P<lat>-?\d+\.?\d+),(?P<long>-?\d+\.?\d+)'

    def start_requests(self):
        FILE_PATH = 'C:/Users/coppe/tutorial/cities.json'
        with open(FILE_PATH) as json_file:
            cities_data = json.load(json_file)
        for d in cities_data:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url='https://www.latlong.net/',
                callback=self.gen_csrftoken,
                meta={'city': d['city']},
                dont_filter=True, # Allow to request multiple time the same URL
            )

    def gen_csrftoken(self, response):
        city = response.meta['city']
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formid='frmPlace',
            formdata={'place': city},
            callback=self.get_geo,
            meta={'city': city}
        )

    def get_geo(self, response):
        lat_long_search = re.search(self.LAT_LONG_REGEX, response.body.decode('utf-8'))
        if lat_long_search:
            yield {
                'coord': (lat_long_search.group('lat'), lat_long_search.group('long')),
                'city': response.meta['city']
            }
        else:
            # Something is wrong, you can investigate with `inspect_response`
            from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
            inspect_response(response, self)
```

The reason why you find (0, 0) is because the lat/long coordinates are displayed trough javascript (they are populated from the backend inside the template).
Scrapy cannot execute javascript without [Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash).

So basically what we are doing, is parsing the JS Script with Regex in order to find the lat/long values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it works fine for me too. How did you know the regular expression to use ? The information was in the html of the page ?

Comment: Yes, the information was in a JS script. You can manually find the information by opening your dev webconsole (right click, inspect) and searching with ctrl+f `sm(`. If you are not familiar with regular expression you can do some test on https://pythex.org/

Comment: Ok thanks. I've tried your code with the complete list of locations imported from a JSON file. The coordinate of the first city is good but not the others. The log is: 2019-04-02 11:38:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.latlong.net/> (referer: https://www.latlong.net/). Should I refresh cookies at each iteration ?

Comment: The reason might be because you need to generate another csrftoken for each city. Let me update my code

Comment: It's quite weird because it works totally fine with the variable "cities" manually created but as soon as I import the JSON file and transform it into an array called "cities" within or outside the spider, nothing works... Any clue ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show me a sample of your json file ?

Comment: I put a piece of the JSON file.

Comment: I have updated the code in order to include the json file inside the `start_requests` method. The code works for me, tell me if it's good for you! :)

Comment: I also have updated the regular expression, which should be better

Comment: This time the code works and iterate well through the JSON but I get the coordinate (0,0) for all locations. Is it an issue with the regular expression ?

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with the regular expression, maybe your ip has been banned ? Have you tried going to the website from your browser ?

You can also use the previous regular expression I gave in my previous answer

Comment: I did both and I can still reach the webpage. Using the former regular expression gives me an error. I guess the last option is that the page does not render the information correctly since I get (0,0) each time.

Comment: The issue comes from the JSON file because when I manually create a variable with the same structure as my JSON, everything works. Maybe there are too many request ? How can I restrict the number of request ?

Comment: You can take a look to `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` setting http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay in order to avoid hitting the server too hard. You can try setting it to 3 for example!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191100/discussion-between-m-coppee-and-sewake).